# Change destination IP of the packet to localhost and redirect it to another port

Tags: iptables, ssh-tunneling, proxy, nat, socks5-proxy

Following is the requirement

1. First, change locally generated requests/packets destination IP to `localhost`. For an example `172.17.0.1:7199` `->` `127.0.0.1:7199`
2. Then redirect this request/packet to the local proxy port(e.g `socks-proxy` port/`redsocks` `12345` port)

How can I do this with `iptables` or any other tool?

---

Following is some more detailed explanation.

I have two servers `server1 - 172.17.0.1`, `server2 - 172.17.0.2`. I need to access `JMX` port (`7199`) on `server1` from `server2`. Since I have disabled remote JMX on `server1`, I cannot access it from `server2` via SSH local forwarding(need to access `7199` port with `localhost` from `server2`). So I have created SSH socks proxy and configured it with [Redsocks](https://crosp.net/blog/administration/install-configure-redsocks-proxy-centos-linux/) tool. It's working fine.

```
# run socks proxy from service2
ssh -v -N -D 9999 user@172.17.0.1

# configure socks proxy with Redsocks in service2
redsocks {
    // redsocks listening port
    local_ip = 127.0.0.1;
    local_port = 12345;

    // socks proxy 
    ip = 127.0.0.1;
    port = 9999;

    type = socks5;
}

# configure iptable rules to route the packets to Redsocks in service2
sudo iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS
sudo iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 7199 -j REDSOCKS
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner <user id> -j REDSOCKS
```

Now if I connect to the `127.0.0.1:7199` from `service2`(e.g `telnet localhost 7199`) it will connect to the JMX port(`7199`) of `server1`. Redsocks route packets correctly to the `server1` via socks proxy.

I have another requirement. When coming packets with IP address of the `service1`(e.g `172.17.0.1:7199`), I need to redirect them to localhost(`127.0.0.1:7199`). For an example, if I connect with `172.17.0.1:7199` from `service2`, I need to redirect it to `127.0.0.1:7199` in order to access the JMX port in `service1` via socks proxy. Normally IP address redirection can be done with one of the following `iptables` rules. Since there are other `iptables` rules existing(related to Redsocks) it does not work.

```
# redirect with host
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 172.17.0.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1

# redirect with host and port
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 172.17.0.1 --dport 7199 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:7199
```

How IP address redirection to `localhost` can be done in this scenario?

Comment: That is not a requirement, that is an attempt at an implementation. Can you add a bit more detail about what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you are new to this, then learn the new `nftables`. It does what `iptables`, `ip6tables`, `arptables`, etc. But easier to use.

Comment: I started to read the new stuff that you added. It the point that I thought "what a about `ssh`" you said that you could not use it (don't know why). Then came the really confusing bit. You then said that you are using `ssh`. At this point I stopped reading.